# Replace Image option is blank?

Tags: texturing, uv, image

The image replacement button is blank after I've tried to replace the skin. When I tried to experiment by going into open new image, I've replaced it. I reversed it, but still can't find a solution after going on forums. Anyone know the solution or can back me up on this?

[image: Image Replacement won't work?]

Answer (score 2):

The image could be "packed" into the .blend, you must unpack to replace it.
You can do this by clicking the small icon shown below, then you should be able to replace it. Remember to "pack" it back if you need to stay in the .blend file!

[image]